# bootstrap tooltip doesnt work in form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2, tooltip

Hey guys I have the following code

```
<?php require_once('header.php')?>

Header looks like this
    <!--vuejs-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
```

custom.js has this line in it

```
$(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

And finally I have a form that look

```
<div id="signupApp">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <form>
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>

        <!--Username-->
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="userName">Username*</label>
            <input v-model="userName" placeholder="Username" v-on:focus="showusernamerequirements" id="userName" class="form-control" id="userName">
            <span v-show="usernameLength==true && usernameHasCap==true && usernameHasNum==true && userexist==false" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Valid"></span>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**But I am having a problem why in the world wont the tool tip work? I should be able to hover over the check mark and see a tool tip that says Valid. But I don't. Any ideas as to why? Do I need to move my cdn links around? Any help here would be great thank ya'll so much! I am sure it is probably something really stupid and I've missed something simple and obvious but I've been messing around with this for an hour and a half and well I would appreciate the help.**

Answer (score 0):

Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library Popper.js for positioning. You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js in order for tooltips to work!

Comment: Whats the cdn for that and if I do that do I need to have <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> still?

Comment: if you add https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js no need add <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>